# How to convert an SQL Datetime value to an XML datetime Value in Groovy Script

Tags: sql, xml, datetime, groovy

I'm new to Groovy script and I was wondering how I could convert a value I got from a SQL database to and XML value?

For example:

I have a variable start_date which contains '2013-04-13 14:34:08'

and I'd like to convert this to:

'2013-04-13T14:34:08'

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `'2013-04-13 14:34:08'.split().join('T')` ?

Answer (score 0):

From a string:

```
def start_date = '2013-04-13 14:34:08'
println start_date.replace(' ', 'T')
```

From a date:

```
def start_date = new Date()
println start_date.format('yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss')
```